# How can I hide file path in server filesystem?

Tags: html

I use Apache Server and upload html page which includes codes below:

```
<img src="http://localhost/public/avatars/2.jpg">
```

and the path of file `2.jpg` is `webrootfile/public/avatars/2.jpg`, which is easily concluded by the `src` attribute.

How can I hide the real path of `2.jpg`?

Comment: Why? What's wrong with the real path?

Comment: Move the file, or write a server-side script to serve content.

Comment: @SLaks, I think it is dangerous while being used by some hackers.

Comment: ha ha why are you trying to hide image path ?

Comment: @SLaks, How can I move the file? Where can I move to?

Comment: @7-isnotbad, I don't want somebody kown my filesystem in my server.

Comment: what about your local urls i mean http://localhost/public/page1.php or xxxx ?

Comment: @7-isnotbad, I test my webpage in a single machine.So the url domin is localhost.

Comment: this is a clip in a github page: 
<img class="avatar from-avatar" height="39" src="https://1.gravatar.com/avatar/ba916cb1c1327b700cf2f753684c2b4f?d=https%3A%2F%2Fidenticons.github.com%2F7b5111cfbe0e2b68b060609e4a088c4a.png&amp;s=140" width="39">
its' src attribute hides the real path. Is it true?? @SLaks

Comment: @user1297181: No; that's a standard Gravatar URL.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are attempting to implement [security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). It's a bit like hiding your key under the welcome mat rather than investing in an electronic keypad or key safe. This is never the right way to approach web security, or any other security for that matter. Rather than trying to hide file paths you should be focusing on eliminating any vulnerabilities that might present themselves once an attacker has the file path.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know whether i get in to what you  try to say

Let a file be **images.php**

```
<?php
$imagetoload=$_Get['image'];
$imageLocation="http://localhost/public/avatars/";
$newImage = imagecreatefromjpeg ($imageLocation.basename($imagetoload)); //aded basename()
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
imagejpeg($newImage);
?>
```

**and you want to get 2.jpg use**

```
<img class="avatar from-avatar" height="39" src="images.php?image=2.jpg" width="39">
```

Comment: This is a _dangerous_ path traversal vulnerability.

Comment: I think the OP needs to first determine what _actual_ security vulnerability he is trying to mitigate before risking the possibility of creating other vulnerabilities to fix a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: @SLaks  may be he can manage it with an Authentication Check before the operation (a user login hash validation etc..)

Comment: Thanks! it is all my want! Since problems exists yet.

Comment: @user1297181 thats al right , think what you want , try to manage security  with an Authentication Check

Comment: @7-isnotbad: That doesn't help at all.

Comment: @7-isnotbad Affirmative

Comment: @user1297181: **Do not use this code**.  Attackers can use it to read anything in your filesystem.

Comment: @SLaks  do you hope imagecreatefromjpeg()  will succeed if $imagetoload is another file (i mean file  type) ? and $imageLocation is internally provided he can also try to make $imagetoload to be a file name not a path + filename

Comment: @SLaks Your case is seem to be:  `src="image.php?../otherfolder"`??

Comment: @user1297181 src="image.php?../otherfolder"  prob is trimmed by basename() see new update

Answer (score 0):

use base 64 encoding format. So Simple file URL will be converted to complex URL and hackers cant see the real paths

```
 <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?= base64_encode(file_get_contents('uploads/images/1.jpeg')) ?>" >
```

Output of this image will be
data:image/png;base64,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